# Update a line instead of drawing a new one?

Tags: javascript, lines

Note: I'm running p5.js

I'm trying to draw a line from where the user started dragging to where they are currently dragging.  How would I go about doing this?

```
mOriginX = 0;
mOriginY = 0;


function mousePressed(){
   mOriginX = mouseX;
   mOriginY = mouseY;
}

function mouseDragged(){
   line(mOriginX,mOriginY,mouseX,mouseY);
}
```

Just makes tons of line from where I originally clicked, how would I make it only draw a single line that is constantly updating its position?

Answer (score 0):

To clear your canvas, use `clear()` function.

Basically, that should do:

```
mOriginX = 0;
mOriginY = 0;

function mousePressed(){
   mOriginX = mouseX;
   mOriginY = mouseY;
}

function mouseDragged(){
   clear();
   line(mOriginX,mOriginY,mouseX,mouseY);
}
```

You can also draw a line and then rewrite it every click:

```
mOriginX = 0;
mOriginY = 0;

function draw() {
   line(mOriginX,mOriginY,mouseX,mouseY);
 }
function mousePressed() {
   mOriginX = mouseX;
   mOriginY = mouseY;
   redraw();
 }
```

Redraw function reference is available [here](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/redraw).

Comment: Replacing what I already have in function mouseDragged() with     
    stroke(255)
    clear()
    background(0)
    line(mOriginX,mOriginY,mouseX,mouseY)     (sorry I can't format a comment) somewhat works, but I can only ever draw one line.  What should I change?

Comment: Have you tried the `redraw` way? And what do you mean saying 'one line'? One line with different points or one with always the same points?

Comment: The redraw method doesn't appear to do anything (this may be of my own fault) and what I mean by only ever having one line is that when I clear() the canvas everything previously on it disappears.